# Joining 3 huge parquet files (each more than memory) using polars

Tags: parquet, python-polars

I have 3 parquet files; each file is more than the memory.

Input parquet Files: Each file has 3M records. Totally 3 files * 3M = 9M records

Max Memory: Memory can hold only 3M records at any given point in time

Max Processing time: It can process max 3M records and then times out

Polars Transformations in AWS lambda:

- Parquet file rows to Polars Lazy Dataframes using scan_parquet
- Operations such as **join**, select, groupby, alias, etc., then
  slice between 0 to 1M and then collect()
- Store to Database
- After processing each chunk of 3M (0 to 1M from each file) pass the next
  batch to the next AWS lambda invocation (2M to 3M records from each file and so on)

Question: Will Polars join the data correctly if the order of the rows of joining columns is not the same across the files? If yes, I would like to know what happens under the hood (to understand it better).

Below is an example,

LazyDataframe1 from file1
col1 [a1...a1M, b1...b1M, c1...c1M] ->(Total 3M)

LazyDataframe2 from file2
col1 [b1...b1M, c1...c1M, a1...a1M] -> (Total 3M)

LazyDataframe3 from file3
col1 [c1...c1M, a1...a1M, b1...b1M] -> (Total 3M)

First run:

```
    lazy_df1 = pl.scan_parquet(file1.snappy.parquet)
    lazy_df2 = pl.scan_parquet(file2.snappy.parquet)
    lazy_df3 = pl.scan_parquet(file3.snappy.parquet)
    
    temp_res = lazy_df1.join(lazy_df2, on='col1', how='left')
    joined_res = temp_res.join(lazy_df3, on='col1', how='left')
    ...#select, groupby, alias
    final_res = joined_res.slice(0, 100000).collect(streaming=True)
    
    print(final_res) #will this work correctly? 

In my understanding, in this run as I am slicing between (0, 1M) it should not work correctly as from each file it will get the first 1M that is,
file1 -> a1...a1M
file2 -> b1...b1M
file3 -> c1...c1M

When I don't slice or stream and load entire Dataframes, it will work as it has all the data in memory
file1 -> a1...a1M
file2 -> a1...a1M
file3 -> a1...a1M
```

Comment: instead of doing collect, try sink_parquet. Collect is going to bring everything in memory whereas sink_parquet will put results in a file so that the results don't need to fit in memory.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor True, [`sink_parquet`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html) would help mitigate the memory constraint issue, since it writes the results to a file rather than bringing everything into memory. That is useful in environments with memory constraints like AWS Lambda. But am I wrong thinking it does not directly address the challenge of correctly joining the data when the order of rows in the joining columns is not the same across files?

Comment: if they're ordered the same then a join will be faster but there is no requirement that they be in the same order, that would make joins pretty useless if they relied on being given data that was already in a 1:1 order

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [polars / Lazy API / Usage](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/lazy/using/) and [Lazy API Query](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/lazy/execution/), I do not see how that would work in a single-machine environment like AWS Lambda, with its processing constraints - memory limit and processing time limit.

In Polars, the [`join` operation on lazy dataframes](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.join.html) is evaluated... well, lazily. Meaning the join operation is not executed immediately, but rather is part of a plan that gets executed when you call `collect()`. That allows Polars to optimize the execution plan which can include reordering operations, predicate pushdown among other optimizations.

But: when the data to be processed exceeds the available memory, and the processing is done in chunks, the `join` operation can become complex.
In the specific scenario you described, where each chunk from different files contains distinct key values (e.g., first chunk: `a1...a1M`, `b1...b1M`, `c1...c1M`), a standard `join` operation within each chunk would not yield any matching rows since the keys from one chunk do not match with keys from another chunk. The `join` operation would not work correctly for such chunks.

Polars alone would not work here: a typical approach in distributed computing or big data processing frameworks would be to use a *distributed* `join` operation, which can handle the shuffling of rows across different chunks or partitions to ensure that matching rows are brought together for the `join` operation.

Such an approach would include preprocessing the data such that the relevant rows for joining are organized together in the chunks that will be processed together. This preprocessing could potentially be done in a distributed computing environment ([AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/), [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/), or a managed [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) service) *before* the data is processed in AWS Lambda.

See as an example "[Part 4. Handling Large Datasets with Polars and Spark: Creating a 100 million Row Fake Dataset in Just 2 Minutes](https://medium.com/@arkimetrix.analytics/polars-and-spark-100-million-row-dataset-18fd29f46d2c)" (Polars and Pyspak: A Powerful Combination for Efficient Data Processing and Manipulation) from [Danny Bharat](https://me.dm/@dannyb)

---

There was also "[`pola-rs/polars` issue 3974](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3974): RAM usage and predicate pushdown"

> Using Polars 0.13.59, I created a DataFrame that occupies 225 GB of RAM, and stored this DataFrame as a Parquet file split into 10 row groups. (For reference, the saved Parquet file is 120.2 GB on disk.) Thus, each row group of the Parquet file represents (conceptually) a DataFrame that would occupy 22.5GB of RAM when fully loaded. I then ran a simple filter query against the Parquet file using scan_parquet, and allowed Polars only 50 GB of available RAM with work with. And it ran successfully. That's an enormous improvement.

But again, would that work in an AWS Lambda environment? I doubt it.